# GitLab inside Docker with Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, ssh, proxy, docker-compose, gitlab

I have a VM with only Nginx and Docker on it. I got a certificate from let´s encrypt for my domain. Inside a docker container I have a GitLab installed. Now I´m trying to reach the GitLab through my Nginx Proxy.

My problem is the SSH access to GitLab, because when I try to redirect the SSH Traffic to my Docker via a stream in Nginx, i got the error "address already in use".

In the Docker I have a adress like "127.240.0.1:22:22" and in Nginx I´m redirecting from gitlab.xyz to 127.240.0.1:22 with proxy_pass on TCP port 22. But this don´t work.

Have you any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this won't work. HTTP(s) clients send a Host header which indicates what address they are trying to reach (gitlab.xyz).

For raw TCP, there isn't a Host header so there is no way to figure out what container should receive the request.

You're getting the "address already in use" because your host already uses port 22/tcp.

We had the same problem and supplied the host with a second IP on which the DNS-Alias redirects. We know all connections to this IP are supposed to go to gitlab. This means you wouldn't even need a reverse-proxy, since you can just open the ports directly into the container. (-p new.gitlab.ip:22:22)

Comment: And how do you do the handling of SSL? Inside the gitlab docker?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how we've handled it, as I currently have no access to the system. But afaik you can still handle all other traffic to gitlab through the reverse-proxy, with the exception of SSH. You could also get the certificates into the container via volume and have a "normal" SSL handling with the nginx inside the container (assuming you're using an omnibus installation).

Comment: I tried your approach to my AWS EC2 instance, but I always get the error: "bind: cannot assign requested address". The Syntax is like: "ports:
    - '1.2.3.4:1337:1337'" and 1.2.3.4 is for example my AWS elastic IP

Comment: Can you add another answer with the output of `docker version`, your new steps to reproduce, your docker-compose.yml and the output of `netstat -tulpn` please? Also I'm assuming you've checked that the IP is actually assigned to the server with ifconfig (I don't know how AWS elastic IPs work)

Comment: The last problem I have is to assign my second Elastic IP to the EC2 Instance, thank you! I will make a new question for that.